# How to get solutions for this system of inequalities?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, numerics, inequalities

I am new to Mathematica and I am struggling finding the solution for the following problem. 
I am studying this piecewise function:

```
Piecewise[{{pdf1[x]/pdf[x] (h + (1 - h) 2 cdf1[x])/(
 h + (1 - h) 2 cdf[x]), 
x < a}, {pdf1[x]/pdf[x] (h + (1 - h) 2 (1 - cdf1[x] + cdf1[a]))/(
 h + (1 - h) 2 (1 - cdf[x] + cdf[a])), 
a <= x < b}, {pdf1[x]/pdf[x] (
 h + (1 - h) 2 (cdf1[x] - cdf1[b] + cdf1[a]))/(
 h + (1 - h) 2 (cdf[x] - cdf[b] + cdf[a])), 
b <= x < c}, {pdf1[x]/pdf[x] (
 h + (1 - h) 2 (1 - cdf1[x] + cdf1[c] - cdf1[b] + cdf1[a]))/(
 h + (1 - h) 2 (1 - cdf[x] + cdf[c] - cdf[b] + cdf[a])), x >= c}}]
```

where

```
pdf1[x_] = PDF[NormalDistribution[1, 1], x]; 
pdf[x_] = PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x];
cdf1[x_] = CDF[NormalDistribution[1, 1], x];
cdf[x_] = CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x];
```

I would like the first and the third piece of the piecewise function to be smaller than a certain value $l$, say $l=0.48$; and the second and fourth piece of the function to be greater than the same $l$.

I managed to represent graphically the piecewise function with the following code:

```
Manipulate[Plot[{Piecewise[{{pdf1[x]/pdf[x] (h + (1 - h) 2 cdf1[x])/(
   h + (1 - h) 2 cdf[x]), 
  x < a}, {pdf1[x]/pdf[x] (
   h + (1 - h) 2 (1 - cdf1[x] + cdf1[a]))/(
   h + (1 - h) 2 (1 - cdf[x] + cdf[a])), 
  a <= x < b}, {pdf1[x]/pdf[x] (
   h + (1 - h) 2 (cdf1[x] - cdf1[b] + cdf1[a]))/(
   h + (1 - h) 2 (cdf[x] - cdf[b] + cdf[a])), 
  b <= x < c}, {pdf1[x]/pdf[x] (
   h + (1 - h) 2 (1 - cdf1[x] + cdf1[c] - cdf1[b] + cdf1[a]))/(
   h + (1 - h) 2 (1 - cdf[x] + cdf[c] - cdf[b] + cdf[a])), 
  x >= c}}], l}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> 3], {a, -10, 10, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {b, a, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {c, b,
   5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {h, 0, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {l, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

The picture is an example of a solution where, for $h=0$, I set $a=0.05$, $b=0.27$ and $c=0.41$ (the yellow line corresponds to $l=0.48$)[image]

What I am interested in is finding for each $h$ the set of combinations of $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that the system of inequalities is satisfied and I need to give a graphical representation of the set of solution somehow.
I have tried something also by defining a domain for $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that $-2<a<b<c<2$, but I feel my skills with Mathematica are too poor to handle the task. Any piece of advice would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Given your description of the problem, `{a, b, c}` are not unique.  For instance, for the parameters in the question, `a` could just as well be `0`.  Please describe more carefully what you are seeking.  By the way,, the last block of code in the question does not execute as written.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I edited the last part of the code and now it should work: the image represented is obtained using the values of the parameters I reported in the post and $h=0$. As you correctly noticed ${a, b, c}$ are not unique: I would like to know, given a certain $h$, all the possible ${a, b, c}$ such that the four inequalities are satisfied, this is what I meant when I said 'the set of combination of $a$, $b$ and $c$. Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to work, but I have not tested it exhaustively.  Define the four curves in the `Piecewise` function as

```
Clear[a, b, c, f1, f2, f3, f4, f]; h = 0; l = .48; SeedRandom[1900];
f1[x_] := pdf1[x]/pdf[x] (h + (1 - h) 2 cdf1[x])/(h + (1 - h) 2 cdf[x])
f2[x_] := pdf1[x]/pdf[x] (h + (1 - h) 2 (1 - cdf1[x] + cdf1[a]))/
    (h + (1 - h) 2 (1 - cdf[x] + cdf[a]))
f3[x_] := pdf1[x]/pdf[x] (h + (1 - h) 2 (cdf1[x] - cdf1[b] + cdf1[a]))/
    (h + (1 - h) 2 (cdf[x] - cdf[b] + cdf[a]))
f4[x_] := pdf1[x]/pdf[x] (h + (1 - h) 2 (1 - cdf1[x] + cdf1[c] - cdf1[b] + 
    cdf1[a]))/(h + (1 - h) 2 (1 - cdf[x] + cdf[c] - cdf[b] + cdf[a]))
```

Then `a` can be no smaller that the value of `x` for which `f2` is equal to `l`, and no larger than the value of `x` for which `f1` is equal to `l`.  Compute these points and place `a` randomly in that range.

```
{amin = a /. FindRoot[f2[a] == l, {a, -1/2}], amax = a /. FindRoot[f1[a] == l, {a, 1/2}], 
    a = RandomReal[{amin, amax}]}
(* {-0.233969, 0.544866, 0.337909} *)
```

Next, `b` can be no smaller than `a` and no larger than the value of `x` for which `f3` is equal to `l`.  Compute these points and place `b` randomly in that range.

```
{bmin = a, bmax = b /. FindRoot[f3[b] == l, {b, 1/2}], b = RandomReal[{bmin, bmax}]}
(* {0.337909, 0.678207, 0.432968} *)
```

Finally, `c` is calculated in a similar manner.

```
{cmin = b, cmax = c /. FindRoot[f3[c] == l, {c, 1/2}], c = RandomReal[{cmin, cmax}]}
(* {0.432968, 0.574512, 0.465049} *)

f[x_] := Piecewise[{{f1[x], x < a}, {f2[x], a <= x < b}, 
    {f3[x], b <= x < c}, {f4[x], x >= c}}]
Plot[{f[x], l}, {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 1000,
    ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {x, f}, LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, Medium}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

The need for reasonable guesses when computing `amin`, etc. with `FindRoot` can be eliminated by using `NArgMin` and `NArgMax` as follows.  (Subsequently edited by including `b < c` in the computation of `cmax` to avoid a singularity in `f3` for some parameters.)

```
{amin = NArgMin[{f2[a], f2[a] > l}, a], amax = NArgMax[{f1[a], f1[a] < l}, a], 
    a = RandomReal[{amin, amax}]}
{bmin = a, bmax = NArgMax[{f3[b], f3[b] < l}, b], b = RandomReal[{bmin, bmax}]}
{cmin = b, cmax = NArgMax[{f3[c], f3[c] < l, b < c}, c], c = RandomReal[{cmin, cmax}]}
```

Incidentally, I have obtained results similar to those above with `h = 0.1` and `h = 0.5`, the latter shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it has been very helpful in proceeding with my work! I am stuck right now on another issue: I would like to represent on a 3d graph the set of the combination of ${a,b,c)$ that satisfies the four inequalities. Would you be able to provide any piece of advice? everything I have tried does not seem to work. Thank you again

Comment: I apologize that I had not accepted your answer until now. I have also posted a new question about the 3d graph. Thank you very much.