# How to represent in a 3D graph the set of solutions to this system of inequalities?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, numerics, piecewise, inequalities

I am studying this piecewise function:

```
Piecewise[{{f1[x, h], x < a}, {f2[x, a, h], a <= x < b},     
{f3[x, a, b, h], b <= x < c}, {f4[x, a, b, c, h],  x >= c}}]
```

where

```
f1[x_,h_] := pdf1[x]/pdf[x] (h + (1 - h) 2 cdf1[x])/(h + (1 - h) 2 cdf[x])
f2[x_,a_,h_] := pdf1[x]/pdf[x] (h + (1 - h) 2 (1 - cdf1[x] + cdf1[a]))/
(h + (1 - h) 2 (1 - cdf[x] + cdf[a]))
f3[x_,a_,b_,h_] := pdf1[x]/pdf[x] (h + (1 - h) 2 (cdf1[x] - cdf1[b] + cdf1[a]))/
(h + (1 - h) 2 (cdf[x] - cdf[b] + cdf[a]))
f4[x_,a_,b_,c_] := pdf1[x]/pdf[x] (h + (1 - h) 2 (1 - cdf1[x] + cdf1[c] - cdf1[b] + 
cdf1[a]))/(h + (1 - h) 2 (1 - cdf[x] + cdf[c] - cdf[b] + cdf[a]))
```

where, in turn

```
pdf1[x_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[1, 1], x];
pdf[x_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x];
cdf1[x_] := CDF[NormalDistribution[1, 1], x];
cdf[x_] := CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x];
```

I want the first and the third piece of the piecewise function to be smaller than a certain value $l$, say $l=0.48$; and the second and fourth piece of the function to be greater than the same $l$.
The following code represents the intervals of $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that the four inequalities are satisfied:

```
{amin = NArgMin[{f2[a], f2[a] > l}, a], amax = NArgMax[{f1[a], f1[a] < l}, a], 
a = RandomReal[{amin, amax}]}
{bmin = a, bmax = NArgMax[{f3[b], f3[b] < l}, b], b = RandomReal[{bmin, bmax}]}
{cmin = b, cmax = NArgMax[{f3[c], f3[c] < l}, c], c = RandomReal[{cmin, cmax}]}
```

Note however that, for example, you have to give a random value to $a$ since the lower bound of the interval of the $b$'s depends on $a$.

I would like to plot in a 3D Graph all the possible combinations $(a,b,c)$ such that the system of inequalities is satisfied. Moreover, I would like to implement the Manipulate command so that I can study how the set of all possible combinations $(a,b,c)$ changes as $h$ varies between 0 and 1.
If a 3D graph was not feasible, actually any graphical representation of the set of solutions of $(a,b,c)$ would be fine anyway.
Thank you if you can help.

Comment: try [`RegionPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RegionPlot3D.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requested plot can be obtained as follows.  First, compute the limits on `a`, using the expressions in the question.

```
{amin = NArgMin[{f2[a], f2[a] > l}, a], amax = NArgMax[{f1[a], f1[a] < l}, a]}
(* {-0.233969, 0.544866} *)
```

Next, compute the corresponding limits in `b`.

```
btab = Interpolation@Table[{a, NArgMax[{f3[b], f3[b] < l}, b]}, {a, amin, amax, .02}];
```

and finally in `c`.

```
ctab = Interpolation[Flatten[Table[{{a, b}, Quiet@NArgMax[{f3[c], f3[c] < l, b < c},
    c]}, {a, amin, amax, .02}, {b, a, btab[a], .02}], 1], InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

Since `a < b < c`, the plot is given by

```
Plot3D[{b, ctab[a, b]}, {a, amin, amax}, {b, a, btab[a]}, AxesLabel -> {a, b, c}, 
    LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}, BoxRatios -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large, 
    Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5]]
```

[image]

where the allowed values of `c` lie between the upper and lower curves (both of which have the same projection on the `{a, b}` plane).  The limits on `a`, `b`, and `c` were obtained [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/182754/1063).

**Addendum**

As noted by [kgir](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr) in a comment above, `RegionPlot3D` also can be used once the logical structure and interpolation functions have been determined.  `RegionPlot3D` is much slower here than `Plot3D` but produces a figure that some may prefer.  The choice is a matter of taste.

```
Quiet@RegionPlot3D[amin < a < amax && a < b < btab[a] && b < c < ctab[a, b], 
    {a, amin, amax}, {b, amin, btab[amin]}, {c, amin, ctab[amin, btab[amin]]}, 
    AxesLabel -> {a, b, c}, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}, 
    BoxRatios -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large, PlotPoints -> 500, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

**Second Addendum**

As noted by the OP in a comment below, the computation of `ctab` given here often fails with the error

> > Interpolation::femimq  The element mesh has insufficient quality of 0.`.

as `h` is increased.  Basically, the triangular grid of `Interpolation` becomes tangled near the edge at which the two curves in the first plot come together.  A simply way of eliminating the error is to replace `0.02` by `0.06` in the computation of `ctab`.  However, doing so decreases the accuracy of the plot significantly for `1/3 < h < 1`.  A much more accurate but slower computation involves replacing the three lines of code immediately preceding the first plot by

```
btab = Interpolation@Table[{a, NArgMax[{f3[b], f3[b] < l}, b]}, {a, amin, amax}, 
    (amax - amin)/20}];
fc[a0_, b0_] := Quiet@NArgMax[{f3[c], f3[c] < l, b < c} /. {a -> a0, b -> b0}, c]
Plot3D[{b, fc[a, b]}, {a, amin, amax}, {b, a, btab[a]}, AxesLabel -> {a, b, c}, 
    LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}, BoxRatios -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large, 
    Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

The resulting plot for `h = 1/2` is

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I have a couple of questions: which value of $h$ did you use to get that plot? The limits of $a$, $b$ and $c$ depends on the $h$ you use. Is there a way to implement something like a Manipulate command so that I can study how the graph changes as $h$ varies?

Comment: I used `h = 0`, but other values of `h` undoubtedly would work.  `Manipulate` would be impractical in this case, because the computation requires several minutes, especially for the second plot.  Please note that I added `b < c` to `NArgMax[{f3[c], f3[c] < l, b < c},  c]` from the other question, which I also updated, to treat unusual cases where `f3` is not continuous.  Incidentally, I soon will replace the two figures with ones of higher quality.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your clarification! I will just produce several graphs for different values of h and then try to come up with some nice way of presenting them. I will check for the higher quality figures then. Thank you for the time you are spending helping me.

Comment: Goodmorning, I hope to not sound impolite by asking again, but I was wondering if you managed to produce the higher quality figures you were talking about in your previous comment. I apologize for insisting, I am trying my best, but my skills in Mathematica are still not enough for this task. Thank you again

Comment: @Api  I replaced the original figures with the new, higher quality figures a few hours after I said that I would.  Please compare them and their associated code with the corresponding material that I originally provided.  The figure made with `Plot3D` was essentially unchanged, but the ragged right edge of the figure made with `RegionPlot3D` was significantly improved. If you click on "edited Oct 5 at 23:06" in red at the bottom of my answer, you can see the changes.

Comment: My apologies, and thank you very much for your help again.

Comment: good morning, I have a question about a part of the code you suggested for my purposes, specifically the part about computing ctab. Whenever I try to run this part after setting values for h different from 0 I get the following messages: "Interpolation::femimq: The element mesh has insufficient quality of 0. A quality estimate below 0. may be caused by a wrong ordering of element incidents or self-intersecting elements." and "Interpolation::fememtlq: The quality 0.` of the underlying mesh is too low. The quality needs to be larger than 0.`." Can you help somehow?

Comment: @Api   The problem is with the `ctab`  `Interpolation` grid near the edge where the two surfaces meet.  A quick fix is to replace `0.02` by `0.06` in the definitions of `btab` and `ctab`, but the plot less accurate for larger `h`..  I would like to find a better solution, however.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you have any idea about how I could generate repetitive graphs for different values of $h$ ? If you can help, I posted a question here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/187551/how-to-generate-repetitive-graphs/187573#187573

Comment: @Api  I have provided the code, but it is slow.

Comment: Sorry if I come to bother you, but your answers always solve my problem. do you know hot to deal with this? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/187998/problem-with-nsolve

Comment: @Api  I do not have time now but will look this evening.

Comment: Thank you,  luckily someone just answered. It's not perfect but I think it should work