# How to generate repetitive graphs?

Tags: plotting, numerics, procedural-programming

I need to create several graph for different values of a parameter $h$.

The code is the following

```
pdf1[x_] = PDF[NormalDistribution[1, 1], x]
pdf[x_] = PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x]
cdf1[x_] = CDF[NormalDistribution[1, 1], x]
cdf[x_] = CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x]
h = 0; l = .48; SeedRandom[1900];
f1[x_] := pdf1[x]/pdf[x] (h + (1 - h) 2 cdf1[x])/(h + (1 - h) 2 cdf[x])
f2[x_] :=  pdf1[x]/pdf[x] (h + (1 - h) 2 (1 - cdf1[x] + cdf1[a]))/(h + (1 - h) 2 (1 - cdf[x] + cdf[a]))
f3[x_] := pdf1[x]/pdf[x] (h + (1 - h) 2 (cdf1[x] - cdf1[b] + cdf1[a]))/(h + (1 - h) 2 (cdf[x] - cdf[b] + cdf[a]))
f4[x_] := pdf1[x]/pdf[x] (h + (1 - h) 2 (1 - cdf1[x] + cdf1[c] - cdf1[b] + cdf1[a]))/(h + (1 - h) 2 (1 - cdf[x] + cdf[c] - cdf[b] + 
    cdf[a]))
amin = NArgMin[{f2[a], f2[a] > l}, a], amax = NArgMax[{f1[a], f1[a] < l}, a]

btab = Interpolation@Table[{a, NArgMax[{f3[b], f3[b] < l}, b]}, {a, amin, amax, .02}];

ctab = Interpolation[Flatten[Table[{{a, b}, 
  Quiet@NArgMax[{f3[c], f3[c] < l, b < c}, c]}, {a, amin, amax, .02}, {b, a, btab[a], .02}], 1], InterpolationOrder -> 1];

 Quiet@RegionPlot3D[amin < a < amax && a < b < btab[a] && b < c < ctab[a, b], {a, amin, amax}, {b, amin, btab[amin]}, {c, amin, ctab[amin, btab[amin]]}, AxesLabel -> {a, b, c}, 
LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}, BoxRatios -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large, PlotPoints -> 500, Mesh -> None]
```

I would like to generate several graphs for different values of $h$, say for $h$ between 0 and 1, with $dh$=0.01.
How can I do this?

Comment: `h = Range[0, 1, 0.01]` will give you a list of h. Then you can either redefince h as a variable in the functions it is used or you can use a loop (`Do`, `Table`) to evaluate along h and produce a list of plots. `Map` and `MapAt` can also work but the syntax is slightly trickier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explicit code needed to answer your question is

```
pdf1[x_] = PDF[NormalDistribution[1, 1], x];
pdf[x_] = PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x];
cdf1[x_] = CDF[NormalDistribution[1, 1], x];
cdf[x_] = CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x];

f1[x_] := pdf1[x]/pdf[x] (h + (1 - h) 2 cdf1[x])/(h + (1 - h) 2 cdf[x])
f2[x_] := pdf1[x]/pdf[x] (h + (1 - h) 2 (1 - cdf1[x] + cdf1[a]))/(h + (1 - h) 
    2 (1 - cdf[x] + cdf[a]))
f3[x_] := pdf1[x]/pdf[x] (h + (1 - h) 2 (cdf1[x] - cdf1[b] + cdf1[a]))/(h + (1 - h) 
    2 (cdf[x] - cdf[b] + cdf[a]))
f4[x_] := pdf1[x]/pdf[x] (h + (1 - h) 2 (1 - cdf1[x] + cdf1[c] - cdf1[b] + 
    cdf1[a]))/(h + (1 - h) 2 (1 - cdf[x] + cdf[c] - cdf[b] + cdf[a]))

l = .48;

Column@Table[
    amin = NArgMin[{f2[a], f2[a] > l}, a]; amax = NArgMax[{f1[a], f1[a] < l}, a];
    btab = Interpolation@Table[{a, NArgMax[{f3[b], f3[b] < l}, b]}, 
        {a, amin, amax, (amax - amin)/20}];
    fc[a0_, b0_] := Quiet@NArgMax[{f3[c], f3[c] < l, b < c} /. {a -> a0, b -> b0}, c];
    Plot3D[{b, fc[a, b]}, {a, amin, amax}, {b, a, btab[a]}, AxesLabel -> {a, b, c}, 
        PlotLabel -> StringForm["h = ``", h], LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 15}, 
        BoxRatios -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large, Mesh -> None, 
        PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 0], 
{h, 0, .98, .49}]
```

[image]

Note that I used the more accurate second addendum to my earlier [answer for a single plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/183159/1063).  I also used `Plot3D` instead of `RegionPlot3D`, because the latter is very slow here.  Even the calculation above is slow, of course.

Answer (score 5):

Something like

```
GraphicsColumn[Table[Plot[some expression with h in it],{h,0,1,0.01}]]
```

perhaps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have already tried this way, but I was not able to solve my issue: as you can see from the code I posted, to obtain my graph I first need to compute two tables, whose values change with $h$. I would need a procedure that, for each $h$ re-run automatically all the code.

Comment: Make a function of `h` that does that. The way to get the most out of *Mathematica* is to compose functions of functions of functions, ...

Comment: I would have done a function to get the graph I need, if I had been able. Unfortunately I could not manage to do so.

Comment: What did you try? Why could you not manage? Can you come up with a **simple** example of the barrier you found?

Answer (score 4):

In all honesty this does nothing more than @John Doty suggested, but it illustrates my point in an earlier comment.

Define

```
h = Range[1, 10, 0.5]
a = 1
b = 1
f[a_, b_, h_, x_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[h, b + a], x]
g[a_, b_, h_, x_] := PDF[InverseGaussianDistribution[a + h, b], x]
```

Then

```
Do[{hh = h[[j]], Print[Plot[{f[a, b, hh, x], g[a, b, hh, x]}, {x, -5, 5}, 
PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]]}, {j, 1, Length[h]}]
```

It will print 20 PDF plots given a and b evaluated over range x, for each value of h. From what I understand in the OP, the part of the code below the definition of `f4` can go into the brackets above, with the plot put inside a `Print`. Also, it looks like the brackets around `amin, amax` are reduntant, but I may be wrong. The operations inside the `Do` loop can be as complex as needed, so the calculation of the tables can be put in directly. Unfortunately I was not able to run the code in the OP and see what I was supposed to get.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I was not able to implement the procedure though

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example in which I use `Manipulate` to plot two graphs for different parameter values. This example may help you to adapt your `code` in a similar manner.

```
Clear[alfa, newalfa, a1, a2, x, s, chn];
Manipulate[
 SeedRandom[s];
 alfa = RandomReal[1, 20];
 newalfa = alfa*(1 + chn);
 Manipulate[
  Plot[{Sin[a1 x], Sin[a2 x]}, {x, 0, 10}],
  Row[{Control[{a1, alfa, Animator, AnimationRunning -> False}]}],
  Row[{Control[{a2, newalfa, Animator, AnimationRunning -> False}]}]
  ],
 {{s, 1, "s"}, 1, 100, 1},
 {{chn, 0, "change"}, -0.2, 0.2, 0.02}
 ]
```

This `code` yields the following graphs.

[image]